# How do I download a package from a specific repository?

Tags: apt, vlc, repository

I want to download the nightly builds of vlc from [here](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily).

I tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt-get update
```

and then when I try

```
agnishom@agnishomPC ~ $ apt-cache show vlc | grep Version
```

I only get the following versions:

```
Version: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4
Version: 2.2.2-5
```

I cannot find the higher versions that are listed on the launchpad website.How do I make this work?

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version? I guess it's Xenial. I don't see a `vlc` package in that PPA for Xenial: https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily?field.series_filter=xenial

Comment: Yep. How do I use the latest vlc, then?

Comment: Two choices: Search for a better PPA, or upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Or install the snap package.